How to hand-hold a large diffuser (4'x6')?
I got a large diffuser:  (https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1739091-REG/neewer_66600166_5_in_1_lighting_reflector_diffuser_kit.html) for an outdoor shoot I was going to have to do at midday on a sunny day. However, with only mild wind my assistant was essentially not able to hold it at all because the sun was almost overhead so it would have to be held quite high and the wind just kept catching it. I know there are "reflector holders" like this:  to attach a reflector to a stand, but for something this big I don't imagine that would be of use. Is there any sort of contraption that would help someone hand-hold this big thing in this type of situation?

Small remark: take in consideration this will be 2 square meters wing...

Related: What cheap equipment can I use to hold a reflector in place?

I am confused because you are posting an image of a reflector, and on the text, it seems you are describing a white diffuser as a sun scrim.
The difference is that a reflector can be held even on the floor because the main goal is to reduce shadows on the opposite side of the sun, while sunscreen needs to be used over the subject's head.

For a reflector, You can make a DIY frame even with PVC pipes. That size is on the upper limit a 3/4 in pipe can handle, but still manageable.
To keep it portable, you can use "T" connectors.

Just look that every connector is tight. If it is not, you can add some tape to the pipe to tighten the connection.
Keep in mind that every connector can reduce the overall structural integrity against torsion.
A reflector can be hand-held by one assistant, which normally is fine if the lower edge is on the floor, which gives a lot of stability when using a frame.

For an overhead diffuser, there are aluminum frames.
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=aluminum+frame+photo+difusser

A large diffuser, a "sun scrim" for safety reasons, IMHO would need to be hand-held by two assistants.
In some promo photos, they show it standing on two C light stands with sandbags, but I would not risk safely leaving them unatended.
You can still make a DIY frame, but I would make that with aluminum tubes or even carbon fiber.
There are no 90° connectors made of aluminum. Here is an adaptation I made (but for other usage) using PVC.

But for a sturdy frame, I would use metallic ones + screws.

Additional note. See if you need a diffuser that large. Probably you can use a smaller, more manageable, 1 person hand-held one.

The reflectors are a zippered "pouch" around the diffuser (so the diffuser is the same shape and can be removed from the reflectors). Sorry for the confusing pictures.

I edited the answer on why I made the difference between the two.
